# PHP based Telegram bot InlineKeyboardMarkup not working

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Trying to create inline buttons for my Telegram bot. this is the request I'm sending and for some reason I don't get the buttons but only the text "Inline Keyboard"

Here is my code

```
$args = [
    'chat_id' => $this->chat_id,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'text' => 'Inline Keyboard',
    'reply_markup' => [
        'inline_keyboard' => [
            [
                [
                    'text' => 'Try me',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$send = $this->api_url . "/sendmessage?" . http_build_query($args);
file_get_contents($send);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem, You must use exactly one of the optional fields .. 'text' field is not enough

Comment: If this fixed your issue, you'd better accept your own answer as the correct answer.

Comment: What exactly is code? What is else fieldsadded? Same problem in sedMessage